# Show tooltip with image content

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I am using qTip2 and I wish to show an image as the tooltip content. I think it can be set by the content property, but I just could not get it right.

I am showing a tooltip on a link:

```
 <li class="answer">We provide personalised <a id="aboutshop" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Shop")">
        shopping list</a> based on what you have in your stock</li>


    // Tooltip for about shop link
    $('#aboutshop').qtip($.extend({}, myStyle, {

    }));
```

Any idea how should I set the content to be an image like this?

```
  <img src="../../Content/HomePage/aboutshop.JPG" />
```

Comment: Allow me to suggest usint TooltipsY. By far the best tooltips jQuery plugin I've used. Lightyears ahead of qTip2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could add the image you want to use in the DOM and then reference it as the text of your qtip:

```
<img id='tooltip1' style="display:none;" src="../../Content/HomePage/aboutshop.JPG" />

$('#aboutshop').qtip({
   content: {
      text: $('#tooltip1') 
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the same way but the tooltip is not shown.. I guess I am going in a wrong direction, the problem seems to be on the usage of tooltip on fancybox...

Comment: I think so because i tried my solution in anotherpage and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I was able to add an image using the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
// Match all <A/> links.
$('a').qtip({
    content: {
        text: '<img src="http://www.ronedmondson.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/smiley-face1.jpg" />'
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the same way but the tooltip is not shown.. I guess I am going in a wrong direction, the problem seems to be on the usage of tooltip on fancybox...

Comment: That's so unfair, you didn't mention anything about fancybox in your question!

Comment: Nice and simple solution, is not documented on the Qtips docs.